# JSONP cannot use results coming from API

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, jsonp

I was trying this to run this ajax request to get a bunch of items and at least log them:

[image]

in the console the items show up as undefined:

[image]

but in the network tab I can see the items that I was trying to call from API:

[image]

I am confused because neither error or success function is triggered.

src code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Hello World</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/fontawesome-free-5.6.3-web/css/all.css">
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/main.css">

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>

<body>

</body>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.3.4/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.js"></script>


<script>
    console.log("alive");

      $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "http://127.0.0.1:3000/api/stories?callback=items",
                dataType: 'jsonp',
                jsonpCallback: 'items',
                jsonp: 'callback',
                success: function(data) {
                    var strData = JSON.stringify(data);
                    console.log(strData);
                },
          error: function(xhr,status,error) {
                    console.log(status);
                    console.log(error);
          }
      });


    console.log(items());

    </script>
</html>
```

Comment: Your API is returning JSON, not JSONP.

Comment: JSONP response looks like `items([  ... ]);` It's a call to the `callback` function, with the object as the function argument.

Answer (score 0):

Try dataType:JSON
 Your API is returning JSON, not JSONP.

Comment: Can`t do that because of cross-origin issue (api port is different from website)

Comment: There is an tricky workaround for that cross origin you can download by using this your problem get solve temporary. 
     https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?hl=en.

Answer (score 0):

do you have cross domain problem? and you want try to use jsonp ?

Comment: Yes, that`s what I am trying to do.